# How to send SMS to multiple receipents in Android?

Tags: android, sms

I want to send 1 message to multiple contact. I searched on that but I cant able to find the solution yet. Can anyone help me? I am stuck on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you add the first contact, simply tap in the contacts field once more, and it will let you add another one.

Edit: Questions regarding the use of your Android phone should probably be posted here: https://android.stackexchange.com/